# Sending a file to a ftp server using ftplib

Tags: python-3.6, ftplib

I'm trying to send a file to a ftp server using the [ftplib library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html).

I have tied two different approaches.

1st)

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('HOST')
ftp.login('USERNAME','PASSWORD')
```

On this case when I try to login I get the following error:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel.
```

2nd)

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftp = FTP_TLS('HOST')
ftp.login('USERNAME','PASSWORD') 
file = open('test.xml','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR test.xml', file)
```

In this case I can confirm that I'm able to connect and login into the server but when trying to send the file, using `storbinary`, I get the same error:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550 SSL/TLS required on the control channel.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding:

```
ftp.prot_p()          # switch to secure data connection
```

After

```
ftp.login('USERNAME','PASSWORD')
```

with that I was able to perform all kind of actions on the ftp server

Comment: I did that but I keep getting the same error